# STL_SCAN data is not accurate over time in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, prometheus

To analyse which Redshift tables are most used. We created a [view](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/184c2ba7fd9d497027a831ca72e08fe09e79fd0b/src/AdminViews/v_get_tbl_scan_frequency.sql). We are exporting the table scan data from this table to Prometheus to see the trends over time.

```
var (
    RedshiftQueryTotalMetric = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Namespace: "redshift",
            Subsystem: "scan",
            Name:      "query_total",
            Help:      "total number of queries executed",
        },
        []string{"database", "schema", "tablename", "tableid"},
    )
)
```

**Problem:**
`sum(redshift_scan_query_total{schema="test_schema",tablename="test_table"})`

I have used Gauge as the increments is not by one but can be multiple, but using Gauge as a counter.

Total queries in a table over 12 hours time should not drop. It should always increase but it keeps dropping.

**Questions:**

1. Why does the value of total scan in STL_SCAN table drops every few hours?
2. How to prevent it from dropping at-least for a day.

[image]

Comment: @john-rotenstein please help out here! not sure why the STL_SCAN data is not accurate

Comment: Is the table regularly re-created, vacuumed or analyzed?

Comment: No, the table is not recreated. We have disabled analyze, we frequently load data in table every 15mins. We dont do VACUUM, aws might do auto vacuum.

Comment: As I understand it, you have a view over `STL_SCAN`, and you use this view to see how many queries have been performed, and every 12 hours or so, the number of queries drops.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes not necessarily 12 hrs, every some hrs it is happening. Yes the view shows the same thing and the query can be this also `SELECT tbl, perm_table_name, COUNT(DISTINCT query) total_queries from stl_scan WHERE tbl='24542984' GROUP BY tbl, perm_table_name;`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are seeing Redshift purging older data from system tables. Redshift only keeps system data for a few days and it clears out older data the totals will drop. Have you looked at the data by start time hour?  I expect you will see that the older hours are removed occasionally.

Comment: Perfect! This exactly was the problem. Thanks. Just released the change to get around this. Now our view is only last 3 days data and we take the last time series value to find the toal queries ran in last 3 days. Our metric is still Gauge as it can drop. Thanks Bill.

Comment: Note I've been told, although whether or not it is accurate is another question, that the system tables purge based on total data size, not based on time.  If you have a busy system, you'll have less days worth of data.

Comment: That is correct.  I’ve seen as little as 3 days so I think there is a floor.